# yarn gets stuck while adding libraries (React Native)

Tags: react-native, yarnpkg, react-native-firebase

I am trying to add the react-native firebase database library in my react native CLI app but yarn gets stuck while linking dependencies and after 5 to mins throws the following error.

```
error An unexpected error occurred: "EBUSY: resource busy or locked, unlink 'C:\\Users\\SAIM NASSER\\Desktop\\E-commerceApp\\node_modules\\react-native-photoeditorsdk\\android\\build\\intermediates\\library_java_res\\debug\\res.jar'".
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you close bundler before you add or remove packages. Since you're on Windows, it could be a file is locked. You can either reboot your computer or use a program to tell you what's locking the file and unlock it. Then you can add/remove the packages, then you can start up the simulator etc. again.